# Jquery Select 2 not showing selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Select2 plugin is not showing selected option with templateFormat option
Anyone knows how fix it ?

markup:

```
<select id="plans" style="width: 75%">
<option value="1" name="text1" price="$1" saving="text" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="2" name="text2" price="$2" saving="text" selected="selected"></option>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('select#plans').select2({
   minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
   templateResult: formatState
});
});
function formatState(state) {
if (!state.id) return state.text;
var html = '<span class="name">' + state.element.attributes.name.value + "</span>"
html += '<span class="price">' + state.element.attributes.price.value + </span>"
html += '<span class="saving">' + state.element.attributes.saving.value + "</span>"
var $state = $(html);
return $state
}
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ed0pL2sd/) of the above code

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  Made the following change and it started working.  I added templateSelection.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('select#plans').select2(
        {minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
            templateResult: formatState,
        templateSelection:formatState
    });     
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to tackle this problem is :

```
// Step1: Here assuming id of your selectbox is my_id, so this will add selected attribute to 1st option 
$('#my_id option').eq(0).prop('selected',true);


// Step2: Now reinitialize your select box

// This will work, if you haven't initialized 
 selectbox $('#my_id').select2();

or

//This will work, if you have initialized selectbox earlier, so destroy it 
  first and initialise it 
 $('#my_id').select2('destroy').select2();
```